# A way to instantly run ERLANG source code files?

Tags: haskell, erlang

Is there any way to run Erlang source file instantly, without the need to compile and then run it?
For example in Haskell platform there is runhaskell(.exe?) command.
I thought maybe there is something similar in Erlang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> escript provides support for running short Erlang programs without having to compile them first, and an easy way to retrieve the command-line arguments.

http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html